# Injection of autowire of dependencies failed while creating spring mvc mongodb project

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, spring-mvc

## Currently I am facing issue while running the spring application in autowire configuration.

**I have attached all the necessary files**

**This is the error**

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.practice.service.CarService com.practice.controller.CarController.carService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.practice.dao.CarDao com.practice.serviceimpl.CarServiceImpl.carDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.practice.dao.CarDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**Here is My Controller class**

```
        package com.practice.controller;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

        import com.mindtree.entity.Car;
        import com.mindtree.service.CarService;



        @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/car")
        public class CarController {

            @Autowired(required=true)
            CarService carService;

            @RequestMapping(value="/details",method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public @ResponseBody
            List<Car> getShopInJSON() {

                    Car polo = new Car("Volkswagen", "Polo");
                    carService.create(polo);

                    Car jetta = new Car("Volkswagen", "Jetta");
                    carService.create(jetta);

                    Car swift = new Car("Maruti Suzuki", "Swift");
                    carService.create(swift);

                    Car ertiga = new Car("Maruti Suzuki", "Ertiga");
                    carService.create(ertiga);

                    Car i10 = new Car("Hyundai", "i10");
                    carService.create(i10);

                    Car i20 = new Car("Hyundai", "i20");
                    carService.create(i20);

                    System.out.println("Find One:- " + carService.find(swift));

                    System.out.println("Find All!!");

                    List < Car > cars = carService.findAll();
                    for (Car car: cars) {
                        System.out.println(car);
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    carService.delete(swift);

                    System.out.println();
                    i10.setModel("i10 Nxt");
                    carService.update(i10);

                    System.out.println("Find All After Update!!");

                    cars = carService.findAll();
                    for (Car car: cars) {
                        System.out.println(car);
                    }



                return cars;


            }

        }
```

**My dao interface**

```
    package com.practice.dao;

    import java.util.List;

    import com.mindtree.entity.Car;


    public interface CarDao {

        public void create(Car car);

        public void update(Car car);

        public void delete(Car car);

        public void deleteAll();

        public Car find(Car car);

        public List < Car > findAll();

    }
```

**My dao impl class**

```
    package com.practice.daoimpl;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.mindtree.entity.Car;

    @Repository("carDao")
    public class CarDaoImpl {

        @Autowired(required=true)
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

        final String COLLECTION = "cars";

        public void create(Car car) {
            mongoTemplate.insert(car);
        }

        public void update(Car car) {
            mongoTemplate.save(car);
        }

        public void delete(Car car) {
            mongoTemplate.remove(car);
        }

        public void deleteAll() {
            mongoTemplate.remove(new Query(), COLLECTION);
        }

        public Car find(Car car) {
            Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(car.getId()));
            return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Car.class, COLLECTION);
        }

        public List < Car > findAll() {
            return (List < Car > ) mongoTemplate.findAll(Car.class);
        }

    }
```

**My entity class**

```
    package com.practice.entity;

    import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

    @Document(collection = "cars")
    public class Car {

        @Id
        private String id;
        private String brand;
        private String model;

        public Car(String brand, String model) {
            super();
            this.brand = brand;
            this.model = model;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getBrand() {
            return brand;
        }

        public void setBrand(String brand) {
            this.brand = brand;
        }

        public String getModel() {
            return model;
        }

        public void setModel(String model) {
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.append("Id:- " + getId() + ", Brand:- " + getBrand() + ", Model:- " + getModel());
            return str.toString();
        }

    }
```

**My service interface**

```
    package com.practice.service;

    import java.util.List;

    import com.mindtree.entity.Car;
    public interface CarService {

        public void create(Car car);

        public void update(Car car);

        public void delete(Car car);

        public void deleteAll();

        public Car find(Car car);

        public List < Car > findAll();

    }
```

**My service class**

```
    package com.practice.serviceimpl;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import com.mindtree.dao.CarDao;
    import com.mindtree.entity.Car;
    import com.mindtree.service.CarService;

    @Service("carService")
    public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {

        @Autowired(required=true)
        CarDao carDao;

        public void create(Car car) {
            carDao.create(car);
        }

        public void update(Car car) {
            carDao.update(car);
        }

        public void delete(Car car) {
            carDao.delete(car);
        }

        public List < Car > findAll() {
            return carDao.findAll();
        }

        public Car find(Car car) {
            return carDao.find(car);
        }

        public void deleteAll() {
            carDao.deleteAll();
        }

    }
```

**My applicationContext.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">



        <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
        <context:annotation-config/>



    </beans>
```

**My webmv-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


        <context:component-scan base-package="com.practice" />




        <mvc:annotation-driven />
    </beans>
```

**My web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">

    <display-name>ProjectServerCode</display-name>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webmvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config/webmvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webmvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
     </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your `CarDaoImpl` has not implemented the `CarDao` interface.

(It lacks `implements CarDao`)

Comment: Maybe it's because of another problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is because your CarDaoImpl is not implementing CarDao interface. Update it and then try

Answer (score 0):

Make autowiring optional:

```
@Autowired(required=false)
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.